login function not working and user details not storing local storage
login.html for the below js
//login.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="signIn">
        <h1 class="form-title">Sign In</h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
          <div id="signInMessage" class="messageDiv" style="display:none;"></div>

          <div class="input-group">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              <input type="email"  id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
              <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            <input type="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password" required>
              <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
          <p class="recover">
            <a href="#">Recover Password</a>
          </p>
         <button  class="btn"  id="submitSignIn">Sign In</button>
        </form>

        <div class="icons">
          <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <p>Don't have account yet?</p>
          <button id="signUpButton">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    
      <script type="module" src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



//login.js

import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-auth.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-firestore.js";
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-app.js";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "-----",  //removed creditinals
authDomain: "login-form-4a49f.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "login-form-4a49f",
storageBucket: "login-form-4a49f.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "660213923239",
appId: "-----"    //removed creditinals
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app); // Pass the initialized Firebase app to getAuth
const db = getFirestore(app); // Pass the initialized Firebase app to getFirestore

const signIn = document.getElementById('submitSignIn');
signIn.addEventListener('click', (event) =\> {
event.preventDefault();
const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) =\> {
showMessage('login is successful', 'signInMessage');
const user = userCredential.user;
localStorage.setItem('loggedInUserId', user.uid);
window.location.href = 'home.html';
})
.catch((error) =\> {
const errorCode = error.code;
if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-credential') {
showMessage('Incorrect Email or Password', 'signInMessage');
} else {
showMessage('Account does not Exist', 'signInMessage');
}
})
})

I am trying to create login page when i started the server. When i first created a login credentials, it is working for the first creds. After then, when i created 2 or 3 accounts, from then it is showing the errors  not storing local storage and cannot access
get error in console with the message:

login.js:39 Uncaught (in promise)
ReferenceError: showMessage is not defined
at login.js:39:12

refering this line
showMessage('Account does not Exist', 'signInMessage');

Even the account details are stored in firebase and entering correct details for login.

The showMessage is defined as:
function showMessage(message, divId) {
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    messageDiv.style.display = "block";
    messageDiv.innerHTML = message;
    messageDiv.style.opacity = 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        messageDiv.style.opacity = 0;
    }, 5000);
}


I'm not aware of a built-in showMessage function in JavaScript. Did you mean to call alert?

function showMessage(message, divId){
var messageDiv=document.getElementById(divId);
messageDiv.style.display="block";
messageDiv.innerHTML=message;
messageDiv.style.opacity=1;
setTimeout(function(){
messageDiv.style.opacity=0;
},5000);
}
it is the function refering that line i was supposed to add that in the code but i forgot

I added the implementation to the question. Going forward you can do that yourself too, by clicking the tiny edit link under your question.

Given the error message the code in your login.js can't find the showMessage function. Where is that function declared? (At this stage I recommend reading how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example, as gathering such a minimal repro interactively is pretty inefficient)
